# Multilingual site. Separate domains. hreflang issues

Tags: multistore, language, multidomain, hreflang

I'm trying to set up a multi-lingual site for a client but having some issues with conflicting ideas.

It's a UK based client selling to the UK and Europe. They'd like to serve different prices for UK customers and International customers. Therefore I've chosen to separate the two sites as two different 'websites' in Magento (as price scope is at website level).

We will use different domains to serve the two websites:

**example.co.uk** (for UK customers) (will have only English language)

**example.com** (for International customers) (will have English and other languages as store views)

The plan was to use hreflang tags to make Google aware of the separation and to avoid duplicate content across the two domains.

The problem is that both the English version of example.co.uk and the English version of example.com would both have to use the same English hreflang tag, causing a potential duplicate content issue once again.

And this is where I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's fairly obvious.

I need to use **en-gb** for the UK site, and just **eu** for the international site:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077